# Error: [filename].txt (No such file or directory) when trying to read in a txt file in Java (Ubuntu cmd line)

Tags: java, command-line-interface

So I'm writing a piece of code that reads in many addresses and then manipulates the data, line by line, then adds it to a Binary Search Tree. However, the file isn't being found no matter what I try. I know the txt file needs to be in the root directory, but (I'm a student) we're required to submit a .tar.gz containing the contents of a directory made specifically for the assignment so I suppose it needs to be in the submitted folder.

I've tried using the "normal" methods I used in IDEs, but they all return the same error.

My code (roughly - obviously you don't really need to see the BST/manipulation stuff), right now, but I've tried every other typical file read-in method:

```
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PrintIt{


public static void main(String args[]){

try{

     File inFile = new File("/bin/testdata.txt");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);





                 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                           String line = sc.nextLine();

                           System.out.println(line); //manipulation in place of this
                           } 
                           sc.close();

                           }catch (Exception e){
                            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }


                                    }


 }
```

I really only need the reading in the file part - the BST stuff/manipulation is just for context, just in case it mattered/there's a better way than reading through each line of the file and adding each to the Tree.

Comment: Use PrintIt.class.getResourceAsStream("testdata.txt"). Becuase there is no bin Folder in your classpath

Comment: ^This seems to work, trying it again. I tried it before but for some reason it didn't work; tried it now and it seems fine. What would follow the line InputStream is = PrintIt.class.getResourceAsStream("testdata.txt") to manipulate it line by line?